# Java - InetSocketAddress hostname with accents

Tags: java, sockets, diacritics, host, hostname

I encounter a problem establishing a connection with an server that has some accents (é è ô...) in its hostname.

For example :

```
String oUrl = "www.hôtel.fr";   
System.out.println(oUrl);
InetSocketAddress isa = new InetSocketAddress(oUrl.toString(), 80);
System.out.println(isa.isUnresolved());
```

The ISA is never resolved. It works for www.google.fr.

I tried to URLEncode the host (URLEncoder with UTF-8 charset, so hostname is www.h%C3%B4tel.fr) with no result.

Does anybody have some clues ? I don't find anything on the web.

Thanks and sorry for my english.

Comment: I tried running your example and I get false returned, i.e. the hostname *could* be resolved into an `InetAddress`. Adding an additional line: `System.out.println(isa.getAddress());` printed: `www.hôtel.fr/81.200.64.50`.

Comment: Damien, Just a FYI, I copied your source code into a test project I have to work on it, and discovered a syntax error in the constructor of InetSocketAddress (it was referencing a non-existent variable before).  I edited your post, didn't want you to be surprised by the edit.

Comment: Tanks Philip. My original source code was a little bit more complex.

Comment: @DuncanJones : it's really strange. I tried on JDK 6 and 7 with a true return. It's perhaps a system managment that differs ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In domain names, umlauts, accents, etc must be converted by punycode. In your example it would end up in `http://www.xn--htel-vqa.fr/`. Without having it tested, the [IDN](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/IDN.html) class might be of help.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this answer ! it work's perfectly with a manual encoding, I just have to use IDN class now

Comment: @Damien If this solves your question, please mark it as the answer.

Comment: sure, i was just waiting to be able to do this (website asked me to wait for few minutes)