# Resolve InetSocketAddress multiple times

Tags: java

As far as I understand if a domain name is provided to `InetSocketAddress` then resolution will only happen once which breaks a scenario when I want to hide a dynamic IP address behind a domain name.

Is there are way to make `InetSocketAddress` resolve a domain name each time it's instantiated? Is this a good way to solve a problem at all, perhaps some better practices exist?

Comment: check this out >  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12075828/java-inetsocketaddress-hostname-with-accents

Comment: @minam.cho does not seem like that question is related.

Comment: What do you mean? When you instantiate `InetSocketAddress` with `new InetSocketAddress(hostname, port)` the inet address is resolved every time. When is it not working for you?